# excel VBA Looping through worksheets : ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Yesterday I decided to learn some VBA to make my excel time easier. It has been going better then expected, but I have been breaking my teeth on this code for many hours now.

I am trying to remove all empty (except title) columns, and this in all sheets of a workbook. 
After lots of googling I managed to find some examples i could adapt to my needs.

I used this code: [remove columns](http://www.excelhowto.com/macros/delete-blank-empty-columns-use-excel-vba/)
and then tried to loop it through the sheets by using dear old microsoft [support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142126)

Together i frankensteined it into this:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long

 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For I = 1 To WS_Count

'removecode

    ' Define the target Range.
      Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).UsedRange

    'Start reverse looping through the range.
     For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

    'If entire column is empty then delete it.
    If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 1 Then
     Columns(iCounter).Delete
    End If

    Next iCounter

'endremovecode

      MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```

When I run this, only the the starting worksheet is cleaned up. The messagebox does loop through all of them.

Why? What am I doing wrong?
I tried finding a solution, but non of the topics here seemed to give more clarity.

Thank a bunch for leading me in the right direction.

Lara

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you should consider changing your for loop to a for each as in: for each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn
```

and

```
Columns(iCounter).Delete
```

are not prefixed with `MyRange` so refer to the active sheet's columns  not the sheet containing `MyRange`. Stick `MyRange.` infront of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just need to qualify your `application.counta` and also your `.columns().delete.` so each is working directly with the sheet in question. Otherwise it's just working with the active sheet.

Try this:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

 For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
    'removecode

    With ws
    ' Define the target Range.
      Set MyRange = .UsedRange

        'Start reverse looping through the range.
         For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

            'If entire column is empty then delete it.
            If Application.CountA(.Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
             .Columns(iCounter).Delete
            End If

        Next iCounter
    End With

'endremovecode

      MsgBox ws.Name

     Next I

  End Sub
```